# write module: npm install missing dist css files

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm writting a small module

now install it somewhere

> cd /tmp
>
> npm install git://xxxx/GongT/mymdl.git

install complete successfull

but file "global.css" gone from `node_modules/mymdl/dist/` folder.

I'm sure that file `node_modules/mymdl/dist/global.css` is in my git repo

whats happend here?

Comment: Is a public repo? If yes, can you share the url?

Comment: git://git.coding.net/GongT/lean-g-loader.git (missing file is "public_files/plugin/bootstrap/css/*.css")I want manage some public file for multiple project, so will not publish to npm